# Dropzone script is not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery

This script is not working as I run and upload a file every time in asp.net mvc.

It just gets stuck in this function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {

        Dropzone.options.dzupload = {

            addRemoveLinks: true,
            success: function (file, response) {
                var imgName = response;
                file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
                console.log("File uploaded")
            },
            error: function (file, response) {
                file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
            }
        }

    };

</script>
```

Comment: warren Sergent  Its still not working ,customize dropzone i created above and you put that in scripts tag but that is still not working , i don't know why...I have been watch in the chrome and done with debugging but its still not working